# Interpolate and extrapolated by group using na.spline() and case_when()

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, zoo

I have some date missing and I would like to interpolate and extrapolate values inside each group even if I just have one value available.

```
#create an example
library(zoo)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(a = c("group1","group1","group1","group1","group2","group2","group2","group2","group3","group3"), b = c(1,2,NA,4,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
        a  b
1  group1  1
2  group1  2
3  group1 NA
4  group1  4
5  group2  1
6  group2 NA
7  group2 NA
8  group2 NA
9  group3 NA
10 group3 NA
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
        a  b b_interpolated
1  group1  1              1
2  group1  2              2
3  group1 NA              3
4  group1  4              4
5  group2  1              1
6  group2 NA              1
7  group2 NA              1
8  group2 NA              1
9  group3 NA             NA
10 group3 NA             NA
```

First, I tried using na.spline by group

```
df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(b_interpolated = na.spline(b, na.rm = FALSE))
```

And give me this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `test`.
x zero non-NA points
ℹ Input `test` is `na.spline(b, na.rm = FALSE)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 3: a = "group3".
```

So I try using na.spline just when any value is available

```
#Interpolate and extrapolate test
test <- df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(test = case_when(all(is.na(b)) == TRUE ~ "empty",
                                                       all(is.na(b)) == FALSE ~ "ok"))
```

That seems work but if I try using na.spline:

```
test2 <- df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(b_interpolated = case_when(all(is.na(b)) == TRUE ~ b,
                                                       all(is.na(b)) == FALSE ~ na.spline(b, na.rm = FALSE)))
```

Then, I got another error again:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `b_interpolated`.
x zero non-NA points
ℹ Input `b_interpolated` is `case_when(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 3: a = "group3"
```

If I use na.approx, group2 can't be extrapolated because just have one value

```
df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(b_interpolated = na.approx(b, na.rm = FALSE, rule = 2))
   a          b b_interpolated
   <chr>  <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 group1     1              1
 2 group1     2              2
 3 group1    NA              3
 4 group1     4              4
 5 group2     1              1
 6 group2    NA             NA
 7 group2    NA             NA
 8 group2    NA             NA
 9 group3    NA             NA
10 group3    NA             NA
```

I don't understand why using case_when give an error, I'm sure that I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the case of na.spline.  Use this to work around it.

In the case of na.approx we use na.fill to extend the data to NA's at the beginning and end.  The second argument of na.fill is a 3-vector which gives the replacement rule for the left end, internal NAs and right end.  It recycles so we can omit the right end.

```
na_spline <- function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NA else na.spline(x, na.rm = FALSE)
na_approx <- function(x) na.fill(na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE), c("extend", NA))

df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(spline = na_spline(b), approx = na_approx(b)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   a          b spline approx
   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 group1     1      1      1
 2 group1     2      2      2
 3 group1    NA      3      3
 4 group1     4      4      4
 5 group2     1      1      1
 6 group2    NA      1      1
 7 group2    NA      1      1
 8 group2    NA      1      1
 9 group3    NA     NA     NA
10 group3    NA     NA     NA
```